# Oreo (8.0) - Remove sms programmatically

Tags: android, database, sms, android-contentresolver, android-8.0-oreo

I can't remove the particular message on Android 8.0

```
    private void foo() {
        Uri dummySms = insertDummySms(context, threadId);
        removeDummySms(context, dummySms);
    }

    private Uri insertDummySms(Context context, long threadId) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("thread_id", threadId);
        values.put("body", "Dummy SMS body.");
        Uri insert = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
        Log.i(TAG, "insertDummySms: " + insert);
        return insert;
    }

    private void removeDummySms(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Log.i(TAG, "removeDummySms: START: " + uri.toString() + " :: " + context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "removeDummySms: END!!!");
    }
```

When I run `foo()` method the logs shows:

```
I/Test: insertDummySms: content://sms/sent//8
I/Test: removeDummySms: START: content://sms/sent//8 :: vnd.android.cursor.item/sms,
```

then it crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
```

The same code works on android 6.x and 7.x

The funny thing: If I remove every sms like this:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null); // where uri is equal: content://sms
```

it works like a charm.

Any ideas why it fails?

Currently I have only one phone with Android O, so I don't know if it crashes on every Android O device. I have `Nokia TA-1004`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively recent change to the `SmsProvider` class kinda broke the expected functionality there. The `Uri` returned from the Provider's `insert()` call was previously figured very simply as:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + table + "/" + rowID);
```

where `rowID` is the return from an `insert()` call on an `SQLiteDatabase`.

For the insertion of a regular, complete SMS message, as in your case, `table` is `"sms"`. However, there are several other tables, mostly used by the system and default messaging app, for which the same `insert()` method is used; e.g., `"raw"`, `"attachments"`, etc. Inserts on these tables resulted in invalid authorities on the returned `Uri`s; e.g. `content://raw/123`.

Newer versions now throw Exceptions on invalid authorities, rather than failing silently, so the `Uri` construction was altered to:

```
Uri uri;
if (table == TABLE_SMS) {
    uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(url, "/" + rowID);
} else {
    uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(url, "/" + table + "/" + rowID );
}
```

and later to:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(url, String.valueOf(rowID));
```

to address issues in the first.

In both revisions, `url` is the one you passed in the `ContentResolver#insert()` call. For the `insert()` call in your snippet, this ends up returning a URI similar to `content://sms/sent/123`, wherein lies the issue. When that is passed in a `delete()` call, it doesn't match any URIs that the Provider's corresponding method deems valid, so it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` of `Unknown URL`.

To fix this, you could construct your own valid URI from the return, as the ID is really all you need to know. For example:

```
Uri del = Uri.withAppendedPath(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, dummySms.getLastPathSegment());
```

However, it is arguably incorrect to do an insert on `"content://sms/sent"` (`Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI`) to begin with. That URI, and the other similar "box" URIs - i.e., `Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI`, `Sms.Drafts.CONTENT_URI`, etc. - are meant to be used with queries, rather than write operations.

You should instead insert on the base `Sms.CONTENT_URI` (`"content://sms"`), and set the `TYPE` to `MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT` in the `ContentValues`. For example, the recommended fix:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, ...);
cv.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, ...);
cv.put(Telephony.Sms.TYPE, Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT);

Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

This will result in a `Uri` that `SmsProvider`'s `delete()` method will recognize, and your delete should succeed as before.